# VBA Formulas populating one line too far

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula that I'm populating that is pretty simple in VBA.  My only issue is this calculation actually goes one line too far, and in my next step I sort descending creating further compounding issues.

Is this code below flawed?

```
Sub Formz()
    
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dinosaurs")
    
            .Cells(2, 9).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(A2="""","""",ABS(G2))"
            End With
            
 
            
              
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, `.Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(lastRow, 9)).Formula = ...`

Answer (score 1):

### Defining a Range

**A Quick Fix**

```
Sub Formz()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dinosaurs")
        .Cells(2, 9).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Formula = "=IF(A2="""","""",ABS(G2))"
    End With
End Sub
```

**Why `- 1`?**

- Because your range doesn't start in the first row.
- The question should rather be *"Why `+ 1`?"*.

  Because

  ```
  Range("A1:A5") = Range("A1:A5).Resize(1, 1)
  ```

  in contrast to

  ```
  Range("A1:A5") = Range("A1:A5").Offset(0, 0)
  ```

  where you will not be using the `+ 1`.

---

```
Sub FormzWhy()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As Long = 9
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dinosaurs")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rg As Range
        
        ' Your way:
        Set rg = .Cells(FirstRow, Col).Resize(LastRow - FirstRow + 1)
        Set rg = .Cells(2, 9).Resize(LastRow - 2 + 1)
        Set rg = .Cells(2, 9).Resize(LastRow - 1)
        ' Your attempt was missing the '- 1':
        Set rg = .Cells(2, 9).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
        
        ' Ben's way (see in the comments):
        Set rg = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, Col), .Cells(LastRow, Col))
        Set rg = .Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))
    
    End With
    
    rg.Formula = "=IF(A2="""","""",ABS(G2))"

End Sub
```

- Note that if e.g. the first row were `4` then it would be `- 4 + 1 = - 3`.